# Copy the range of cells with Ctrl+A

Tags: vba, excel

Please clarify me what is problem with this copy method?

```
Range("A6").Activate
Range("A6:"  "UsedRange").Copy
```

Comment: what do you want to do?

Comment: I just try to copy range of cells like shortcut ctrl+A in excel.

Comment: and what range do you want to copy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the [range.CurrentRegion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-currentregion-property-excel) property, not worksheet.UsedRange.

```
Range("A6").CurrentRegion.Copy
```

CurrentRegion mimics a single ctrl+A on the worksheet. It references a range of cells radiating out from its parent range in all directions until a full blank row, a fully blank column or an edge of the worksheet is met.